# How can I simplify and enhance multiple if-statements usage?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

So I'm just curious and trying to improve my current application. Couldn't really find any examples of this.

I've got a bunch of checkboxes `cbc`in my form and I want to do something if none of them is checked.

Is there any better ways to do this?

```
      If Not cbc1.Checked = True Then
        If Not cbc2.Checked = True Then
            If Not cbc3.Checked = True Then
                If Not cbc4.Checked = True Then
                    If Not cbc5.Checked = True Then
                        If Not cbc6.Checked = True Then
                            If Not cbc7.Checked = True Then
                                If Not cbc8.Checked = True Then
                                    If Not cbc9.Checked = True Then

                                        'Do this and that

                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

I find this a bit messy and its probably not a good way to write a good code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [.All() from LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx)? It's cool (and readable)

```
Dim checkBoxes As New List(Of CheckBox) From {cbc1,cbc2,cbc3} 'all your check boxes
If checkBoxes.All(Function(cb) Not cb.Checked) Then
    'Do this and that
End If
```

Also you don't need to do `if boolObj = True Then`. Just `if boolObj Then` is fine.

Edit: The condition was the other way round. Fixed now.

Comment: Jack, that it exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for good explaining and spot on answer! :)

Comment: No problem. But you should check out on how to use `AndAlso` too (as mentioned by others). My answer is sort of the fancy way.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm going to. Though I found your way very readable, so I might stick with that unless it has any huge downsides compared to `AndAlso`. :)

Comment: The downside is it runs slower and use more memory. But the difference is practically zero in this case(unless you have like 100000 check boxes in the list).

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't doing anything, except in your last If statement, why not use AND operator and combine all the boolean checks ?
That way you will only have one if then end if loop.

Comment: `AndAlso` is better in this case, apart from `And` it will only keep checking if no statement so far has returned `False`.

Comment: I would love to see how the `and` operator would work in my example since I'm not familiar with the and or `andalso` as @VisualVincent mentioned. Though I found Jack's answer to solve my problem perfectly. Not sure which way would be best.

Comment: @MadsTheMan : Jack's is probably the best as it's easier to read and customize. The `And`/`AndAlso` operators works like this: `If cbc1.Checked = True AndAslo cbc2.Checked = True AndAslo cbc3...` and so on. See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx _(note that you can use as many `AndAlso`'s as you like in one line)_

Comment: Ah alright, thank you for explaining that for me @VisualVincent. Got it.